# How can I get the mqtt broker url starting with 'mqtts://'?

Tags: mqtt

My situation is currently

1. I succeeded in sending data to my ubuntu mosquitto on Amazon webservice using node-red. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59557479/what-server-address-mosquitto-broker-url-should-i-use-to-connect-node-red-to-m/59558566?noredirect=1#comment105287324_59558566)
2. The next thing I need to do is replace 'node-red' with a site called 'loriot' and send the data coming to 'loriot' to mqtt 
   (you don't have to know 'loriot'. It just sends data.)
3. I entered ip adress(MQTT broker url) in 'loriot' just as I did in node-red, but no data is sent. I saw the log of 'loriot', and the url I entered was prefixed with 'mqtts://'.

Questions

1. The '54.180.126.214:1883' I entered in node-red is invisible, but is it a sentence like 'mqtts://54.180.126.214:1883' ??
2. If it's another sentence, how can I get the mqtt broker url starting with 'mqtts://' ??

picture explanation

1. photo1 is the information I entered in the node-red.
2. photo2 is the information I entered in the loriot.
3. photo3 is the loriot's log. If you look closely, I typed '54.180.126.214: 1883' in photo2, but the log says' mqtts://54.180.126.214:1883'. Probably loriot's mqtt has 'mqtts://' set to default.

**photo 1**
[image]

**photo 2**

[image]

**photo 3**
[image]

Comment: Port 1883 is normally for MQTT, for MQTT over TLS (mqtts://) the normal port is 8883. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59562215/edit) the question to include your mosquitto config so we can see how you have set up the TLS listener

Comment: Also I have removed the Node-RED tag, because this question is about how you setup loriot, not Node-RED

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mosquitto broker doesn't look to be configured with a TLS listener (`mqtts://`)

Also since it has a bare IP address it is unlikely to have a proper TLS certificate which will also make connecting over TLS harder.

Your broker is currently configured with a bare MQTT (`mqtt:\\`) listener on port 1883. So your connection URL for loriot should be:

```
mqtt://54.180.126.214:1883
```

If loriot requires a MQTT over TLS (`mqtts://`) connection then you will need to first get a TLS certificate, then configure the broker to use it. You should probably get a hostname for the machine first.

p.s. You should probably enable authentication (and disable anonymous access) on your broker now you have published it's IP address to the world.